# Multiple line user input in Python

Tags: python-3.x, input

I want to know how to write an input that accepts a string with multiple lines, so I can run code on that string. (In Python 3.6)

My code is so far like this:

```
inp = input()

def isVowel(c):

    """
    Pré-condições: Receber um carácter para analisar
    Pós-Condições: checar se é ou não uma vogal
    """

    if(c in 'aeiouáéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôûAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÃÕÂÊÎÔÛ'):
        return True
    return False

def eraseVowels(string):

    """
    Pré-condições: Recebe um string
    Pós-Condições: Eliminar as vogais
    """

    new_str = ''
    for c in eraseExtraBlanks(string):
        if not isVowel(c):
            new_str += c
    return new_str

def eraseExtraBlanks(string):

    """
    Pré-condições: Recebe uma string como input
    Pós-Condições: eliminação dos espaços supérfluos
    """ 

    string = string.replace('  ',' ')
    if('  ' in string):
        return eraseExtraBlanks(string)
    return string.strip()



print(eraseExtraBlanks(eraseVowels(inp)))
```

Comment: You could simply call `input` again after it returns to get the next line. And so on. This of course requires some sort of stop criteria, like 2 empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

I Think This Is Helpful For You

```
print("give the input here ")
contents = []
while True:
try:
    line = input()
except EOFError:
    break
contents.append(line)
```

Comment: Still does not work, it just keeps asking for lines. I would like it to read a multiple line string , and then work the code on it.....